# How do i check if a cost function is Concave or Convex?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, som, convex-optimization, concave

[image: Self Organising Map Cost Function]

How do i check if this cost function is concave or convex? I also want to find if this has a single or multiple minimums.

Effort Made;

```
   function [w,pi,costvalue] = main_cost(inputdata, tmax,   alpha_ini,somrow,somcol)
   %main cost function; To get cost value for all possible random weights
   %Input:
   %inputdata : Data sample
   %tmax : Maximum Iteraitions - This determines the number of generated
   %random w and pi with cost function computation for each set. 
   %alpha_ini : The learning rate
   %Somrow,somcol : map size 

   %Output
   %w: Som weights 
   %pi: Global weights
   %costvalue: cost for a set of w,pi and input data

   %Example
   %load expdata_normalized;
   %[w,pi,costvalue]=main_cost(expdata_normalized,500,0.1,5,5);

   N = somrow * somcol; %all neurons
   Dimension = size(inputdata,2);%input data dimension
   % Get the corresponding 2D locations of the N neurons on the map
  [u(:,1) u(:,2)] = ind2sub([somrow somcol], 1:N);
  alpha = alpha_ini; %set initial learning rate

  %set map effective width
  sigma_ini = 2;
  sigma = sigma_ini;


  %initialise costvalues
  costval=zeros(1,tmax);

  %for 1 to max iterations
  for t = 1:tmax
  tic
 %generate random SOM weights
 w{t} = round(rand(N,Dimension),1);
 %generate random Global weights
 pi{t} = round (rand(1,Dimension),1);

% For 1 to all samples in the data
for j = 1:size(inputdata,1) 
   % Pick a single sample
    samplei = inputdata(j,:);
   % make global weight same dimension with SOM weights
    pirepmat = repmat(pi{t},N,1);
    % determine the winning node, from weights at iter(t) to picked
    % sample
    bmu = part1_closestNeuron(samplei, w{t},1,pirepmat);
    % calculate neighbourhood for SOM at iter (t)
    for k = 1:size(w{t},1)
        neighbourhoodF = exp(-eucdist(u(bmu,:),u(k,:), somrow, somcol, 1)^2 / (2*sigma^2));
        allneighbourhoodF(k)= neighbourhoodF;
    end
    % now get cost value with; inputdata(all-static), Somweights at
    % iter(t), and Global weights at iter(t)
    costval(t) = costval(t)+CostFunction_iter(inputdata, w{t},pi{t},allneighbourhoodF);
end
toc
end
costvalue = costval;
end
```

What i tried doing in the code above is to get a random weight values as inputs for the above cost function, then calculate the cost value for those random inputs with a sample that doesn't change, if i find multiple minimum cost, then that confirms that my cost function is not convex.

My code is slightly different from the cost function i posted in my question, as i have an additional input. As an output from my implementation, i have the cost values for different weights against my sample, now i am having trouble visualizing this.

Comment: Please read the [SE policy on homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Gist is: if you do not show any effort, it is off-topic and likely to be closed within the hour.

Comment: Hello Adriaan, Thank you. Firstly, this is not a home work. I need suggestions as i believe there are different ways of finding this out. In regards to the effort i made; please see code below;

Comment: Thanks Adriaan, now i have uploaded the code. The long explanation of what i tried doing is the reason i didn't upload the code in the first place. But i hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for uploading the code. This is a good question now!

Comment: It might still be more viable for mathematics.SE

Comment: I have no idea wtf is going on with this code... closestNeuron? learningRate? SOM weights? lol? Where did this code come from?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn what convexity is. For the short version, [check Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function).

For a more detailed version, I recommend [this lecture 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3W_wFZ2kUo&list=PL3D9A62846A129C47&index=2) and [this lecture 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcOodzDGV4c&list=PL3D9A62846A129C47&index=3) of Boyd's course on convex optimization.  The beginning part of that course introduces a bunch of useful math for identifying/checking convexity.

If a function is *not* convex, you can disprove convexity by finding a counterexample:

- Graph the function if 2d or 3d.
- Plot the value of the function applied to convex combinations of two random points and look for non-convex regions.

Convexity is violated if there exists two points `x` and `y` along with a scalar `a` in `[0,1]` such that `a * f(x) + (1-a) * f(y) < f(a*x +(1-a) * y)` (basically somewhere with a downward curve).

Failing to disprove convexity is *not* the same as proving convexity! Some approaches to prove convexity are:

- Show Hessian is positive semi-definite.
- Apply the definition of convexity directly (show def. satisfied for all possibilities)
- Show the function is convex by construction rules... eg. the pointwise maximum of a set of convex functions is convex. etc... apply theorems like that.

---

Glancing at the posted image, a norm is always convex (consequence of definition). A sum of convex functions is convex, but I don't know what that K thing is...

Comment: Many thanks Mathew, "Plot the value of the function applied to convex combinations of two random points and look for non-convex regions" this is exactly what i did in my code above, i randomized the input values and got a cost value for each combination. now the trouble i am having is the plotting in 3D space, any suggestions on this? i tried plots like;  ' scatter(costvalue,randomvalX,randomvalW) '.  this looks very random.

Comment: If you pick two points `x` and `y` and plot the value of the function for all points between `x` and `y`, that is a 2d graph, not a 3d graph. On the y-axis you have `f(a*x + (1-a) *y)` and on the x-axis you have `a`, which will run from 0 to 1. This does not prove convexity, but it allows you to disprove convexity if that graph ever curves downward.

Comment: Alright i understand this, although my cost function above is slightly different and more complicated, i have more than one value for the initial x and y points, i am dealing with neuron weights (y) which have the same dimension with my data sample (x), and the 'K' you were asking is a neighborhood value i calculate with every combination of X and Y,  could you advice further on the initial random values? I think i am doing this wrong.

Comment: @Young_DataAnalyst This isn't a programming problem. This is a math problem.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot check this by *simulation*.

Convexity is a property you need to check on paper, by looking at the derivatives of your cost function. This strictly needs to be solved *mathematically*, not with matlab example simulation.

Comment: I disagree to some extent. You can DISPROVE convexity by simulation. Throwing a function quickly into /Applications/Grapher.app on the Mac can give you intuition. For higher dimensional problems, you can generate random points in MATLAB then plot every convex combination of the two points on a graph. If the graph curves downward anywhere, it's not convex.

Comment: Of course you can disprove; but if you don't find a counterexample you know nothing.